# How do I use the result of jQuery validation to change other elements

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using remote validation on a textbox and I am returning an object from the validation service with properties which should be used to populate other elements on the form.  I have the following code in the rules options for my form:

```
 <%= Job.UniqueID %>:{
    remote: 
    {
        url: "ComboBox.svc/ValidateJob",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            criteria: function()
            { 
                return $("#<%= Job.ClientID %>").val(); 
            }
        },
        success: function(data,textStatus,XMLHttpRequest){
            // Load elements from data parameter
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

My success callback is called, but the validator callback in `jquery.validate.js` is not, so I do not see the message when validation fails.  If I remove the success callback above I do see the error message.

I'm suspecting that this is not the correct place to but I'm not sure where else I should attempt this, perhaps I should use `validator.addMethod`?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `invalidHandler` callback function to display the errors.

Comment: I'm not submitting the form at the point of validation so invalidHandler is not being called, I'm getting the validation on a change event thank you for the reply though.